# Properties convention approach

Tags: vb.net

As far as i know there is convention by Microsoft to not use underscores when using Properties, however they said it can be used for private fields (not sure). So cinsidering following situation when having class:

```
class Sample

Property Name as String

Private _margin As Decimal = Nothing
        Public Property Margin As Decimal
            Get
                Return _margin
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                _margin = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Margin")
            End Set
        End Property
End Class
```

In this case for `Name` property i could just simply call it using:

```
Name = "John"
```

or in constructor to avoid parameters same names to use:

```
Me.Name = "John"
```

That's clear. However when we talk about full properties i cannot just use in case of `Margin` property - `margin` as private backing fields as this will show error (same name) so i could just use as i shown `_margin` with underscore (is it ok by the way?).

However this comes to mess in code as for Name property i would call just by `Name` and for `Margin` i could call it with underscore `_margin`. :

```
Name = "John"
_margin = "whatever"
```

Keep in mind i would prefer to not name private properties differently than property name.

Comment: Margin isnt a private property

Comment: Why do you put c# tag when there's no c# code at all.

Comment: @Plutonix i ment _margin as private my bad

Comment: Looks like your question is purely about coding style (about whether it is ok to use underscore prefix) which is completely opinion based. You may want to [edit] the post to clarify if you actually have non-opinion based part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However this comes to mess in code as for Name property i would call just by Name and for Margin i could call it with underscore

No, you couldn't. If you use the underscore in that case, you are accessing the field, not the property. **And you shouldn't be writing code that does that**, i.e. which accesses the field instead of using the property.

The underscore in the name is fine, according to many conventions (including the Microsoft conventions you imply you want to follow). But the only code that should access the backing field is the property itself. All of the rest of your code should use the property name, i.e. `Margin`.

Comment: ok so i can just call it everywhere from class/outside by calling Margin. But what about underscore which is still for backing private field? In C# i think i could use same name with lowercase, here i cannot and in regarding Microsoft convention i should prevent underscores. How to avoid that?

Comment: @Tony: I don't understand what you're asking. The class member `_margin` is a private field, not a property, and you've already acknowledged that the Microsoft conventions are accepting of field names with leading underscores for private fields. Where's the conflict?

Comment: I've made mistake and to be honest i am not sure whether should i use underscore or something else in that case? In C# we can name private variable of property with same lowercase name therefore it led us to not use underscore at all name. What should i do in this case - still keep underscore or not?

Comment: @Tony: even in C#, where there's a difference between upper- and lower-case, I use underscores for private members. IMO, you should use underscore for private fields, as in `_margin` above. But even according to the Microsoft conventions you're referring to, this is allowed.

Comment: So simply saying what i've just presented is correct way of use - please of cofirmation. Is there any situation that i should call instead of Margin, the _margin (i saw some people do it very often) and you said to not call _margin at any time just Margin.

Comment: There is no "correct" or "incorrect" way - there are conventions - suggestions only.  Microsoft will not electrify your keyboard if you stray.  Quite frankly coding conventions are fluid - if you are a consultant they can vary from site to site by amounts large and small.  The code I write in SO answers is a bit different from code I would use in an app (different context, different audience, added clarity etc) @Tony

Comment: @Plutonix: _"There is no "correct" or "incorrect" way"_ -- agreed. But to be clear, there _is_ a "correct way" to follow the published Microsoft conventions. Which is what the OP appears to be trying to do here.

Comment: @Plutonix what's your take then on that then? If my approach is one of the correct once what is then use of _margin as Peter said to not use it anytime and call it using Margin. Therefore i read it as bad habbit to call it using _margin instead of Margin.

Comment: @Tony: _"as said to not use it anytime"_ -- you seem to still not understand. No one has actually said what you are saying has been said. The Microsoft conventions you describe specifically allow its use for a private field, and you've even said that in your own question. That's about as opposite of "not use it anytime" as you can get.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes but you said "And you shouldn't do that" therefore my question would be is there any situation that i should use _margin instead of Margin?

Comment: @Tony: when I wrote "you shouldn't do that", that is in reference to _"accessing the field"_, not the naming. I will edit the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Summarizing what i understood so far is that what i wrote is one of the correct approaches and to keep in mind to not call propertie's field but Property itself - always (within the class or outside the class). Is that all correct what i just wrote? As very last question why then people are calling backing field in my case _margin? Is it wrong in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, I think the code you show in your question is fine. And yes, if you find code that accesses a property's backing field directly, instead of going through the property itself, I would say that's _in general_ wrong. I can't rule out the very rare scenario where doing so is necessary and/or desirable, but absent any other information, it's my opinion that one should not be doing that. The field should be considered private to the property, inaccessible by any other code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho is that the way following my example that you also uses in your projects or you use diffrent approache? Especially using underscore for backing private field? Thanks to all your feedack here.

Comment: @Tony: I "practice what I preach". I use leading underscores for names of private class members, and I restrict access to a property's backing field to that property itself. In a situation where it seems like I need to break this second rule and access the backing field with code outside the property implementation, I refactor the code so that the design is a better abstraction of what I want, and so that it does not violate the basic principle of property implementation encapsulation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho so you do as i mentioned in main post Underscore for private as do readonly for setter perhaps to restrickt access to backing field am i right?